# Can I increase padding around paragraphs in IntelliJ displayed Javadocs?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

As per this screenshot, IntelliJ just isn't doing a great job of rendering paragraphs in the Javadoc view (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) - not enough space around them.

[image: Javadoc view]

On the other hand, Javadocs in `render Javadoc` mode (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>) is great, but requires you to view the class in the editor - not as handy as (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>), especially when you are trying to read the Javadocs for auto-complete options.

[image: Render Javadocs]

Comment: Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-229463